# Android Studio Emulator - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

I am trying to start the emulator in Android Studio on Ubuntu, but
it is not working. I am able to create a new device in the AVD-Manager, 
however nothing appears If I am trying to start it.

I am running Android Studio 2.3.1 on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and I followed this guide:

https://github.com/uw-it-aca/spacescout-android/wiki/1.-Setting-Up-Android-Studio-on-Ubuntu#install-intels-kvm-for-better-avd-performance

My hardware configuration :

[image]

Maybe I must install my graphics driver correctly? I have an Nvidia GTX 580

However, I am stuck at point 8, because it says that I must do something in the emulator tab, but there is no emulator tab in android studio (Android Studio 2.3.1)... Sorry for my english

Comment: you can try alternative emulators, which don't require any additional manual setup, like Genymotion.

Comment: What is the hardware configuration your PC/ Laptop?

Comment: Before you start Android Studio, try 'export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1' and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem when launching Android Studio with sudo command. In my case files for emulators were being created in *root/.android/avd* however, for reasons unknown to me, Android Studio was looking for them in *home/.android/avd* folder. Copying all files from one location to the other fixed it.

Comment: Thx for the hint, however in my case the files for the emulators are not created in the root folder....cant find any "avd folder" in my android folder..I can only see a folder called : "emulator" in home/android/sdk

Comment: Make sure that you enter .android not Android folder, it's a hidden file so check 'Show Hidden Files' in your nautilus browser

Comment: Yeah I did, I have no .android folder in my root folder and I also checked if the avd-files are created in the home/.android/avd folder and it seems that they are created correctly..I can see two files; Nexus_5X_API_25.avd and Nexus_5X_API_25.ini