# android studio emulator not showing and working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-16.04, android-sdk-2.3

I am following this below links:
https://cialu.net/solve-android-studio-avd-issue-with-ubuntu-16-10/
[Android Studio Emulator - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513175/android-studio-emulator-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

I have tried a lot but not able to resolve it

Comment: Any error shown ?

Comment: No error is showing

Comment: Have installed KVM ?

Comment: No, I didn't install that. Can you please refer me?

Comment: https://github.com/uw-it-aca/spacescout-android/wiki/1.-Setting-Up-Android-Studio-on-Ubuntu